# After a $.ajax request, is there any way to get the request's params from the response?

Tags: jquery, ajax, response

If I make a jQuery AJAX call:

```
 $.ajax({url: 'example.com', data: {bar: 2}).done(handleResponse);
```

is there any way I can get the parameters I passed to the AJAX request (ie. the data option) from inside the response handler?  In other words I'd like to be able to do:

```
handleResponse = function(response) {
     var requestData = response.something.something.data;
     // requestData.bar == 2
}
```

And just to be clear, I know I can do it by using a "partial" from a library like underscore, ie.:

```
 var data = {bar: 2};
 $.ajax({url: 'example.com', data: data).done(_(handleResponse).partial(data));

handleResponse = function(data, response) {...
```

but I was just wondering if there was any other (cleaner) way to do it using the arguments jQuery passes to the response handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't quite understand the rest of your code, but given the first part:

```
$.ajax({url: 'example.com', data: {bar: 2}).done(handleResponse);
```

you can access the data in the handler:

```
handleResponse = function(response) {
     var requestData = this.data;
     // requestData.bar == 2
}
```

`this` contains the options passed to `$.ajax` unless you also passed a `context` option.

Comment: That's great, but a couple things: 1) is it not possible to get that info from the arguments (as it's often convenient to bind handlers to another `this`, which would make me lose `this.data`)? 2) `this.data` looks like `bar=1&bax=2&...`; does the data exist in a more friendly (ie. JS object literal) form?

Comment: 1) correct, you can't get it to the arguments. 2) that's very interesting... i didn't expect it to give you the $.param()'d version of it. Could probably use an existing querystring parsing plugin if you didn't want to write one yourself.

Comment: Gotcha; well, response.foo.request.data would have been nice, but `parse(this.data)` is better than nothing.  Thanks.